# Url Referrer in ASP.NET Core MVC not working

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My ASP.NET Core C# project contains 3 pages:

1. Dashboard
2. Home
3. Teacher

All of the above 3 pages redirect to the `DetailsPage`.

On the `DetailsPage`, I have placed the one-button GO BACK.

```html
<button id="GoBack" type="button"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rounded text-dark backButton">
        <img src="BACKBUTTON.jpeg">
</button>
```

In my action result, I am trying the redirect to a specific page from where I came from but it is not working.

```cs
public IActionResult RedirectFromWhereCamefrom()
{
    //string referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
    //return new MvcHtmlString(referrer.ToHtmlString().Replace("value=\"\"", String.Format("value=\"{0}\"", referrer)));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dashboard.cshtml

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Dashboard</h1>
    @{
        var parms = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "from", Context.Request.Path } };
    }
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="DetailsPage" asp-all-route-data="parms">DetailsPage</a>
</div>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public IActionResult DetailsPage(string from)
{
    return View();
}
```

DetailsPage.cshtml

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">DetailsPage</h1>
    <button onclick="window.history.back();">Go Back</button>
</div>
```

[Repo](https://github.com/ChrisWong979/url-referrer-in-asp-net-core)

The original url(Dashboard/Home/Teacher), could be passed as parameter to controller. It could be further passed to the view.

Comment: That I know but I want to use MVC... Can u please suggest? Because I want to store the link in DB as well to perform other operations...